# How to enable form autocomplete in angular application

Tags: angular

I migrated an app to Angular and now it does not autocomplete the form upon returning page visits. Otherwise it works perfectly fine.

My gut feeling is that it has to do with the *ngIf template expressions and just the general non-static nature of Angular but I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to perhaps enable the form to autofill?

**login.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <hr>
      <form autocomplete="on">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="email" required [(ngModel)]="email" autocomplete="email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required [(ngModel)]="pass" />
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button (click)="Register()">Register</button>
          <button (click)="Login()">Sign In</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-login *ngIf="!loggedIn"></app-login>
```

Comment: I think is because autocomplete="email" should be autocomplete="on"

Answer (score 2):

The input attriubte `autocomplete` has only two values `on` and `off`. To enable autocomplete you would want to use `autocomplete="on"`. Your code should look like the following:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="email" required [(ngModel)]="email" autocomplete="on"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `autocomplete` set up properly as an html attribute of your `input` element, but you've set it equal to `"email"`, which is not a valid value.

Review the [documentation on autocomplete](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp).

If you set `autocomplete="on"` your code will work.

The code working with this change: https://jsfiddle.net/pdzb02yk/2/